# Processing JSON response in node server and front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a node server that's sending a JSON response but how come I have to do `res.json()` again on the frontend in order for my response to work?

Also, what is the ideal convention for handling a fetch on the frontend? Like how should I structure my async/await function?

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const TRANSLINK_TOKEN = 'j2bXKzENILvyoxlZ399I'
const TRANSLINK_URL = 'http://api.translink.ca/rttiapi/v1/buses?apikey='

// API routes
app.get('/buses/location', async (req, res) => {
  const apiURL = `${TRANSLINK_URL}${TRANSLINK_TOKEN}`
  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiURL, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }})
    const jsonResponse = await response.json()
    res.send(jsonResponse)
  }
  catch (e){
    console.log(e)
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

App.js

```
  fetchLocation = async () => {
    let locationURL = "/buses/location"
    fetch(locationURL)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          res.json()
          .then( (result) => {
            this.setState({
              active_vehicles: result
            })
          })
        }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do res.json because the body of an HTTP response is just a string. There is no way for the code to know what format the string is in unless you tell it, which is where res.json comes in: you're telling the code to parse the string response as JSON and return the resulting object.

As for structure, if you're already using an async function on the front-end, you should use await there, too, to help flatten the code:

```
fetchLocation = async () => {
   let locationURL = "/buses/location";
   const res = await fetch(locationURL);
   if (res.ok) {
     const result = await res.json();
     this.setState({
       active_vehicles: result
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: If I'm doing `response.json()` in my server, does that do anything? Like I still have to parse it again on the frontend?

Comment: Your server is using fetch to get a response from another API. That will come to your server as a string of bytes, and you need to tell Node to parse it as a JSON object. Then when you send it back to your client, it will be sent again as a string, and the client needs to parse it back into JSON. Objects can't be sent across HTTP, they must be stringified first. You could use `res.text()` on the server and it would work just fine, as it gets converted to text during transmission anyway, but either way, you do need to parse the response on both ends.

Comment: To add a bit of clarity: the `fetch` function doesn't resolve with the response body. It resolves with a Response object that has the body string along with other information such as response headers. Without using res.text() or res.json() or similar, you only have access to the full Response object, not the actual body of it, which is the data you really want here.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the nature of how `fetch` is implemented in the FE. It doesn't automatically parse responses to json.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

You could use a third party library that handles content-type for you (like `axios`) - or you could write a simple function that wraps `fetch` if you are confident that everything returned from the server is going to be valid `json`s.

btw since you are already using `async` you should use `await` instead of `then`/`catch`:

```
  fetchLocation = async () => {
    try {
    let locationURL = "/buses/location"
    const response = await fetch(locationURL);
      if (response.ok) {
        const result = await response.json();
        this.setState({ active_vehicles: result });
      } else {
        // you probably should handle cases when response is not ok - fetch doesn't throw errors for 4xx, 5xx, 3xx codes.
      }
    } catch(e) {
      // handle request failure here.
    }
  }
```

Comment: If I'm doing `response.json()` in my server, does that do anything? Like I still have to parse it again on the frontend?

Comment: Nah it doesn't do anything that affects the FE. When transferring data over the network your `json` is still going to be converted to strings. (and usually applications rely on the `Content-Type` header to decide how to parse the string)

Answer (score 2):

With `fetch` you need to use the `res.json()` every time you make an `HTTP` request.

Your server is making a `GET` request to `api.translink.ca`. When `res.json()` is called it handles asynchronous tasks that are called in lower levels of your system to actually receive and read data.

Your client is also making a `GET` request but instead of making that request to `api.translink.ca` it's making it to to your host. If you're running your server on your own computer that would be `localhost` and the full URL is `localhost/buses/location`. The fact that you're making another `GET` request is why you need to call `res.json()` again.

To your second question, convention is a matter of preference.

`await` is just syntactic sugar to avoid something called [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Just resolve the final values you get from promises to the variable your expecting and try to keep your code as readable and tidy as you can.

E.g.

Updating your code:

```
fetchLocation = async () => {
  let locationURL = "/buses/location"
  let res = await fetch(locationURL);

  if (res.ok) {
    let result = await res.json();
    this.setState({ active_vehicles: result });
  }
};
```